# Emulation of different arch's address space

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-management, virtual-machine, portability

I'm currently writing a simple emulator of hardware which have different architecture and CPU instruction set than a common x86 PC. The question is how to emulate the random-access memory for this hardware.

I suppose the better way is to allocate a large chunk of continious memory and map it to the address space of a hardware being emulated. But this hardware has 32-bit address space and is supposed to be able to run greedy C++ programs or even managed environments. Also, large address ranges in this emulated memory will newer be used, so i need sparcity.

My current approach is based on MS Windows-only function VirtualAlloc(): `VirtualAlloc(NULL, physBytesToAllocate, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_TOP_DOWN, PAGE_NOACCESS)`

When I get SEH exception after a first attempt to read or write to an address from the reserved range, I extract the pointer to yet-non-existing address of memory and commit a single page with another VirtualAlloc() call, with different parameters: `VirtualAlloc(ptr, ..., MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);`. After that, i return the control to the point where SEH exception initially appeared (`EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION` ).

But, IMO, this whole approach smell. It lloks like hackery, it is not portable, in the first place, and require SEH. So are there better ways?

Comment: Did you look at the code of existing multi-platform emulators like QEMU?

Comment: I prefer to keep this project small and simple, so i'm working with the memory just like i've got a large array while in fact memory consumption is low because 99.9% of the pages is not committed. I don't even check addresses in the opcode emulation routines, when they require an address i just add the location of my array. After brief examination of the qemu code i have a feeling that they're implemented their own VirtualAlloc() and maintain their own translation pages. That will be a major complexity increase.

Comment: Well, emulation/virtualization support is not (or has been not) a major feature in OSes, much less part of any practical standard (like POSIX). While it's almost always possible to implement in one way or another, there will always be issues to deal with in the OS or its APIs.